# Freight on a World without Oceans

Tags: transportation

The world is a planet with an extremely smooth surface, so that there are no significant pools of water. The ground is usually dry, but there is rain, which is absorbed into the ground and cycles around due to plants. Apart from the smoothness and lack of seas, the planet is very earth-like, with the same spin rate, distance to the sun, etc. There are humans on this world, living in cities around the globe. What, using modern technology, would be the most efficient way to transport goods (specifically goods usually transported by sea in real life) between cities?

Comment: Wouldn't they use current methods of land transportation: planes, trains, trucks?

Comment: The most efficient mode of transportation of freight overland is railroads, obviously. We all know that. Why are you asking as if it's something to think about?

Comment: Nebraska has no oceans. You could check what they use there.

Comment: No water bodies means little to no evaporation, which means little to no rains, which means little to no vegetation. We are not talking about Arrakis here?

Comment: P.S. I am curious about the miraculous mechanism which maintains a very smooth surface of a fertile plain full of plants, expecially in the presence of rain. (And presumably cultivated by those people who need to transport freight.)

Comment: There's no way this planet would support life or have rain without open bodies of water.

Comment: There is not going to be a single answer. Different freight has differing needs and values. Nobody is going to fly 40 tons of (commodity) corn to a processor, and nobody is going to entrust medical transplant organs or valuable documents to a 65km/h freight train. For some freight, departure time is more critical than arrival, and for others the reverse is true. There are entire college majors devoted to calculating logistical "efficiency". Without some constraints, this question seems Too Broad.

Comment: It would be a desert world.  If the earth were flat, it would not lack oceans, it would lack dry land.  Also, where is the water going to evaporate from to become rain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Canoes, then barges on canals, then trains, canals, trucks and situational air.

If there is lots of rain and it is flat, I am going to assume a moon less, with minimal plate tectonics. There will need to be lots of lakes and small rivers. Think Canadian shield and its lakes and rivers. The large number of small lakes are needed if there is to be temperature regulation/moderation and to allow for the evaporation-rain cycle.

With the extensive rivers and lakes, canoes and portaging will be the most common form of transport for early peoples.

Mid term small river barges will be used extensively until trains can be established. Historical precedence is the canals like were built and used in Europe during 1500(?)-1900 prior to trains being more economical.

Places that remain unfrozen but have extensive seasonal flooding (think Amazon basin) will likely remain canal and barge based even with modern tech. Bridges are expensive so it is quite possible that trains and barges will remain dominate with only limited use of trucks. Multiple Venice like cities could be possible.

Air: situational, air is always more expensive the ground/water.

#### Consider containers

Another thing to consider: containers. Containerization allowed massive shift of production from dockside to wherever. It is also a key enabler for globalization. Without large ships, containerization will take longer before it arrives on scene. Which means large concentrated manufacturing hubs will persist longer in this world.

Answer (score 4):

With modern technology, we use trains, trucks and airplanes to transport stuff where there is no river or sea available for boats. Even when there is a sea or river, sometimes we use those, because in many cases boats would be more expensive.

Think of the USA - it is one of the biggest countries in the world, with most states landlocked and you don't have a river network connecting the whole country. When you ship stuff from California to New York it may go by land or air, but never by water (unless you are ordering a Yatch, which might make its way through Panama).

Or think of Europe. You got a nice railroad network that connects practically the whole continent. You can go from Lisbon to Bucharest all by railroad if you wish. I think a lot of intracontinental cargo travels by road or rail there too.

Comment: There are also  many canals in Europe connecting many river systems.

Comment: @M.A.Golding yes, but can you from Prague to Rome on a boat?

Answer (score 2):

Mag-lev trains will be the most efficient, given the needed scale, more traditional trains may still be extremely prominent (practicality to build the infrastructure).

I want to add more... but idk if there is more to add.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your world could have a type of giant railroad to do the job that cargo ships do.  Say, an ultra-wide track standard, consisting of many parallel railroad tracks 30m wide in total.  The train that travels on this standard would be as large as a cargo ship and support its bulk on all tracks at once.  The ultra-wide trains would travel only between the biggest world cities.

Facilities like ports would connect the ultra-wide railroads to standard railroads and trucks for distribution to smaller cities and towns.

Answer (score 1):

I could imagine the single largest difference would be the heavy reliance on air because of the shear scale and spread of the population over a massively larger landmass then we have now. Current transport methods would still be common but air would be a much larger component of that.
Air transport would likely include various sizes of aircraft but it seems logical that extremely massive aircraft would also be utilized for very long distances between popular hubs. Making huge flat runways would be easy in a huge smooth world.

It seems logical that if the world is very flat with little to no features that the local geology and soil hardness would be very consistent over a large area including the distribution of valuable resources. So not only could the soil be much easier to tunnel in for a larger area but much more of it would have to be mined for an equivalent real world amount of raw resources.

I would add that it's strikes me as very likely tunneling and large man made caves would be a massive part daily life and if the water table was in reach we could add large underground aqueducts to the list of transport methods. As well as many other uses for the tunnels.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how smooth the surface is, there are two ideas i had that could work out:

1. Sleds
   If the surface is extremely smooth with little to no resistance, powered sleds might proof profitable, as they do not need established infrastructure.
2. Hovercrafts
   Same idea as sleds, but suitable for more rough terrain ("rough" as in "rougher than absolute flat"). We already possess this technology, so it is feasably and practical.

Answer (score 1):

Canals.

There are no natural oceans, but nothing stops people from digging a huge trench between major cities and waiting for it to fill with rainwater.  The result could allow the passage of big cargo ships with higher capacity than a railroad and capable of carrying large objects (LNG spheres, prefab buildings, airplane parts) that would not fit on a normal railroad.  It could also be lower maintenance than the equivalent number of railroads, since you don't have to maintain and replace the rails.

Comment: An Earthlike planet without oceans would need to have an absurdly shallow water table, so merely the digging would be sufficient.  I can only assume some vagary of the biology ordinarily plugs such things up.  In modern times it would seem more trouble than rail, but think of the tourist value!  The only beaches in the world - ride the waves when the big ships pass.  Also, they might have been dug out in pre-industrial times.

Answer (score 0):

**Rockets.**

Freight will be lifted by rocket / rockaloon / rockaloonannon to appropriate altitude, where it will pause and allow the rotation of the planet to bring the destination closer.  High winds at great altitude will be used to change latitude.  This entails an up front energy investment but this is recouped in the form of less frictional losses over long boring overland journey.

And also what is the point of building a world that just uses the same effective but tired stuff we have in our world?  Rock rock, rockaloonanoon!